# spark structured streaming can not find structured_network_wordcount.py

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to Spark and learning from the structured streaming [tutorial](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html). Using spark 2.4 with python.

I run `nc -lk 9999` in a terminal. Then in a notebook, run below based on the tutorial

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to localhost:9999
lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "localhost") \
    .option("port", 9999) \
    .load()

# Split the lines into words
words = lines.select(
   explode(
       split(lines.value, " ")
   ).alias("word")
)

# Generate running word count
wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()

 # Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
query = wordCounts \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("complete") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Now on a different terminal, I go inside my s`park-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7` folder and run

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit examples/src/main/python/sql/streaming/structured_network_wordcount.py localhost 9999
```

Which gives me error

```
Error executing Jupyter command '/Users/myusername/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/python/sql/streaming/structured_network_wordcount.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But I know the `structured_network_wordcount.py` file exists in that location. Then why is this error?